# Using combination of JSON.stringify and encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpexcel

So I hava a JSON stored in a variable

```
var x = '{"time":"Friday, January 15, 2016 9:13 PM","keywords":"social","tweets_people":[{"text":"@FreeformTV I want to see what my social DNA looks like! #FreeformLaunch","username":"bbjeagle","user_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/681285613526515712/H6aB4gS__normal.jpg","timestamp":"2016-01-15T15:42:59.000Z","display_name":"JOY","language":"en","tweet_id":"688023580240670720","location":"united_states","location_details":{"country":"united_states","type":"country"},"retweet_count":0,"reach":531,"favorite_count":0,"sentiment":84,"entities":{}},{"text":"#IBM Scoops Up IRIS Analytics Fraud Detection Firm https://t.co/6oisTfWGNq #technology #enterprise #social #tc","username":"chriswrighttech","user_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/577224176542445568/1N2FMNHV_normal.jpg","timestamp":"2016-01-15T15:42:55.000Z","display_name":"Chris Wright","language":"en","tweet_id":"688023567221534721","location":null,"location_details":null,"retweet_count":0,"reach":458,"favorite_count":0,"sentiment":-50,"entities":{"urls":[{"display_url":"goo.gl/fb/weklj1","expanded_url":"http://goo.gl/fb/weklj1","url":"https://t.co/6oisTfWGNq"}]}},{"text":"Handbook of Statistical Modeling for the Social and Behavioral Sciences https://t.co/qCbResQLzK https://t.co/sLf2uhhUQd","username":"allwood_mary","user_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/653044576501035008/VWEwjp_N_normal.jpg","timestamp":"2016-01-15T15:42:49.000Z","display_name":"Mary Allwood","language":"en","tweet_id":"688023541023924227","location":null,"location_details":null,"retweet_count":0,"reach":52,"favorite_count":0,"sentiment":34,"entities":{"urls":[{"display_url":"uae-trip.info/p/tr/?query=ht…","expanded_url":"http://uae-trip.info/p/tr/?query=http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19…=2&toolid=10039&campid=5337597384&item=151951539608&vectorid=229466&lgeo=1","url":"https://t.co/qCbResQLzK"}],"photo":[{"display_url":"pic.twitter.com/sLf2uhhUQd","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/allwood_mary/status/688023541023924227/photo/1","type":"photo","media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYxZw96WsAAzzvk.jpg","resolution":{"w":242,"h":400,"resize":"fit"},"url":"https://t.co/sLf2uhhUQd"}]}},{"text":"Philasmicos R5 CRM (Standard) #Business Social Networking #Mac App... https://t.co/88YCSejyyE #socialnetworking","username":"marac00per","user_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/509110528208142336/Ah4ZC3vh_normal.jpeg","timestamp":"2016-01-15T15:42:42.000Z","display_name":"Mara Cooper","language":"en","tweet_id":"688023510111916032","location":"miami","location_details":{"country":"united_states","city":"miami","state":"florida","type":"city"},"retweet_count":0,"reach":33649,"favorite_count":0,"sentiment":0,"entities":{"urls":[{"display_url":"goo.gl/fb/7hwwhZ","expanded_url":"http://goo.gl/fb/7hwwhZ","url":"https://t.co/88YCSejyyE"}]}}],"tweets_media":[{"text":"The Peach app is dead, but it taught us this about social media: https://t.co/0IJsSnb2z2 https://t.co/iqu71DKk4L","username":"NewRepublic","user_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/631195731756388352/rXgYnC9S_normal.jpg","timestamp":"2016-01-15T15:40:22.000Z","display_name":"New Republic","language":"en","tweet_id":"688022921747533824","location":"washington","location_details":{"country":"united_states","state":"washington","type":"state"},"retweet_count":0,"reach":139506,"favorite_count":0,"sentiment":35,"entities":{"urls":[{"display_url":"bit.ly/234xz4y","expanded_url":"http://bit.ly/234xz4y","url":"https://t.co/0IJsSnb2z2"}],"photo":[{"display_url":"pic.twitter.com/iqu71DKk4L","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/NewRepublic/status/688022921747533824/photo/1","type":"photo","media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYxZM7FWMAMxrSz.jpg","resolution":{"w":1024,"h":532,"resize":"fit"},"url":"https://t.co/iqu71DKk4L"}]}},{"text":"FG will ensure social welfare for the poor – Osinbajo https://t.co/KDwyJnbAgj via @todayng https://t.co/BPpQ7GE4Gi","username":"NigeriaNewsdesk","user_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/559635895909752832/5m7oAlGi_normal.png","timestamp":"2016-01-15T15:39:37.000Z","display_name":"Nigeria Newsdesk","language":"en","tweet_id":"688022736917118980","location":null,"location_details":null,"retweet_count":2,"reach":1070269,"favorite_count":0,"sentiment":0,"entities":{"urls":[{"display_url":"today.ng/news/national/…","expanded_url":"https://www.today.ng/news/national/66295/fg-will-ensure-social-welfare-for-the-poor-osinbajo?utm_source=dlvr.it_nnd&utm_medium=twitter","url":"https://t.co/KDwyJnbAgj"}],"photo":[{"display_url":"pic.twitter.com/BPpQ7GE4Gi","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/NigeriaNewsdesk/status/688022736917118980/photo/1","type":"photo","media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYxZCKsWYAI0NZw.jpg","resolution":{"w":1024,"h":806,"resize":"fit"},"url":"https://t.co/BPpQ7GE4Gi"}]}},{"text":"Building your personal brand on social media is as much about listening as talking. https://t.co/U8VwyRYgD6 https://t.co/1qes1tfVMB","username":"FT","user_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/466972537704824832/eflEColL_normal.png","timestamp":"2016-01-15T15:09:50.000Z","display_name":"Financial Times","language":"en","tweet_id":"688015237958774784","location":null,"location_details":null,"retweet_count":0,"reach":2190381,"favorite_count":0,"sentiment":35,"entities":{"urls":[{"display_url":"on.ft.com/234vi9l","expanded_url":"http://on.ft.com/234vi9l","url":"https://t.co/U8VwyRYgD6"}],"photo":[{"display_url":"pic.twitter.com/1qes1tfVMB","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/FT/status/688015237958774784/photo/1","type":"photo","media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYxSNpKWMAArwFh.jpg","resolution":{"w":600,"h":338,"resize":"fit"},"url":"https://t.co/1qes1tfVMB"}]}},{"text":"Who has decided that women cannot go in?: Ranjana Kumari, Director, Centre for Social Research on #SabrimalaRow @LRC_NDTV","username":"ndtv","user_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/570440108424171520/QuGYd7jH_normal.png","timestamp":"2016-01-15T14:46:17.000Z","display_name":"NDTV","language":"en","tweet_id":"688009314565550080","location":"india","location_details":{"country":"india","type":"country"},"retweet_count":15,"reach":5824509,"favorite_count":6,"sentiment":0,"entities":{}}],"topUsers":[["FreeformTV",678,"100%"],["AsMickymouse82",141,"-100%"],["ILoveMyDinoMatt",120,"0%"],["CloudataNow",79,"12%"],["TheSocialMs",79,"100%"],["mhsowrove",75,"100%"],["TSM_B2B",70,"100%"],["ExploreWeb2dot0",61,"-4%"],["Go2WebMarketing",61,"-4%"],["dreckbaerfrau",58,"100%"]],"locations":[["london",523],["new_york",321],["chicago",238],["los_angeles",204],["toronto",156],["kota",152],["atlanta",129],["miami",121],["mumbai",106],["boston",104]],"time_series_mentions":{"14/01/2016_15:43":1501,"14/01/2016_16:43":1592,"14/01/2016_17:43":1692,"14/01/2016_18:43":1477,"14/01/2016_19:43":1537,"14/01/2016_20:43":1864,"14/01/2016_21:43":1313,"14/01/2016_22:43":1448,"14/01/2016_23:43":1498,"15/01/2016_00:43":1289,"15/01/2016_01:43":1094,"15/01/2016_02:43":1313,"15/01/2016_03:43":1337,"15/01/2016_04:43":1075,"15/01/2016_05:43":1069,"15/01/2016_06:43":1053,"15/01/2016_07:43":808,"15/01/2016_08:43":844,"15/01/2016_09:43":524,"15/01/2016_10:43":973,"15/01/2016_11:43":1148,"15/01/2016_12:43":1313,"15/01/2016_13:43":1272,"15/01/2016_14:43":1277},"time_series_impressions":{"14/01/2016_15:43":9631791,"14/01/2016_16:43":24597649,"14/01/2016_17:43":42674232,"14/01/2016_18:43":61093552,"14/01/2016_19:43":70688408,"14/01/2016_20:43":47669000,"14/01/2016_21:43":24028898,"14/01/2016_22:43":76327602,"14/01/2016_23:43":50294599,"15/01/2016_00:43":74220157,"15/01/2016_01:43":45603520,"15/01/2016_02:43":29450814,"15/01/2016_03:43":46223938,"15/01/2016_04:43":15439446,"15/01/2016_05:43":19868983,"15/01/2016_06:43":82828364,"15/01/2016_07:43":98291003,"15/01/2016_08:43":11781541,"15/01/2016_09:43":8872385,"15/01/2016_10:43":4314408,"15/01/2016_11:43":14093326,"15/01/2016_12:43":10846241,"15/01/2016_13:43":8302175,"15/01/2016_14:43":18581107},"time_series_sentiment":{"14/01/2016_15:43":60,"14/01/2016_16:43":67,"14/01/2016_17:43":55,"14/01/2016_18:43":69,"14/01/2016_19:43":69,"14/01/2016_20:43":61,"14/01/2016_21:43":61,"14/01/2016_22:43":58,"14/01/2016_23:43":54,"15/01/2016_00:43":61,"15/01/2016_01:43":68,"15/01/2016_02:43":60,"15/01/2016_03:43":59,"15/01/2016_04:43":57,"15/01/2016_05:43":50,"15/01/2016_06:43":70,"15/01/2016_07:43":70,"15/01/2016_08:43":61,"15/01/2016_09:43":73,"15/01/2016_10:43":66,"15/01/2016_11:43":68,"15/01/2016_12:43":70,"15/01/2016_13:43":66,"15/01/2016_14:43":67},"relatedTopics":[["@Waze",1745,-76.9],["@Freeformtv",1229,100],["#Freeformlaunch",1215,100],["#Gopdebate",693,-14.1],["#Social",668,45.2],["@Arsenal",493,-99.2],["@Elnennym",490,-100],["#Socialmedia",364,66.4],["#Marketing",261,62.2],["@Realdonaldtrump",236,69],["@Gurmeetramrahim",223,100]],"media":{"mentions":145,"impressions":230059822,"sentiment":"20%"},"people":{"mentions":30311,"impressions":895723139,"sentiment":"25.2%"}}';
```

I know this is avalid JSON ([check here](https://jsonblob.com/56991474e4b01190df499dc1))

Now when I try to pass it to `encodeURIComponent()` to make it URL Safe, it doesn't encode it properly. I don't know why is it happening.

I want to pass this JSON to a PHP file from which i want to genrate a Excel file (genrated using this JSON data) using PHPExcel. I am doing this so that I can redirect the user to the php page passing this JSON as a GET parameter and which will download the file (as default behaviour of PHPExcel is it stores the file in filesystem) directly to the client without storing it to the filesystem.

By the way is it doable using AJAX, making an AJAX call to the PHP file passing this JSON as a POST data and, the PHP file builds EXCEL and respond with the excel file without uploading it to the server so that it can be directly downloaded to the client.

Comment: "it doesn't encode it properly" — How does it encode it? How does that differ from how you expect it to be encoded?

Comment: _as default behaviour of PHPExcel is it stores the file in filesystem_ -- make a tempfile (with `tmpfile()`) and return it using `readfile()`. You could also use a memory stream but I doubt PHPExcel supports that.

Comment: The results of passing that to `encodeURIComponent` look fine to me.

Comment: Maybe the data is too long for the url.

Answer (score 2):

Your string is 8951 long before encoding, read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string) to see why your GET query fails. Change your Ajax call to POST and that will work.

```
// x is not a string anymore, but a JSON object
var x= {"time":"Friday, January 15, 2016 9:13 PM", .... } ;
$.post ('myurl.php', x, function (ret, status) { ... }) ;
```

Comment: @void, did i help?